# How do I export AEM reports in Excel?

Tags: aem

I'd like to to export AEM reports, page activity or component activity reports, in an excel file.

Is this feature is available in AEM or do I have to write custom for this?

Comment: As a hint - you need to use something to generate Excel document. I would recommend to use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: How did you solve this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: Found an useful workaround. I will post it as answer.

Comment: acs-commons has reporting module starting AEM 6.3. https://communities.adobeconnect.com/p00jkz7g8mub

Comment: Thanks @phemanthkumar28 I wanted to point that as well. ACS Commons is now much better than the legacy Comp Reports.

Comment: There is simple workaround without need for writing custom code. I wrote it in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you will get is a CSV selector that can convert report data to CSV but even that has limitations (pagination, filters may be ignored depending on the report).

This, AFAIK, is not an OOTB function. There are old posts and blogs out there to show how this can be done on bpth client side (using JS) or server side using CSV writers.

If you are going down the route of writing a custom solution (most likely outcoume), have a look at the CSV text library that is used in acs-commons user CSV import/export utility, that makes the job really easy and is already a part of AEM.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The **WriteExcel** class simply takes the List collection that is used to populate the **JTable** object and writes the data to an Excel spreadsheet.

This class uses the **Java Excel API**. The Java Excel API dependency that is required to work with this API is already in the POM dependencies section.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import jxl.CellView;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.format.UnderlineStyle;
import jxl.write.Formula;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableFont;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;


public class WriteExcel {

    private WritableCellFormat timesBoldUnderline;
    private WritableCellFormat times;
    private String inputFile;

    public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public int write( List<members> memberList) throws IOException, WriteException {
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        workbook.createSheet("Comumunity Report", 0);
        WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        createLabel(excelSheet)   ;
        int size =  createContent(excelSheet, memberList);

        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();

        return size ;
    }

    private void createLabel(WritableSheet sheet)
            throws WriteException {
        // Lets create a times font
        WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10);
        // Define the cell format
        times = new WritableCellFormat(times10pt);
        // Lets automatically wrap the cells
        times.setWrap(true);

        // create create a bold font with unterlines
        WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false,
                UnderlineStyle.SINGLE);
        timesBoldUnderline = new WritableCellFormat(times10ptBoldUnderline);
        // Lets automatically wrap the cells
        timesBoldUnderline.setWrap(true);

        CellView cv = new CellView();
        cv.setFormat(times);
        cv.setFormat(timesBoldUnderline);
        cv.setAutosize(true);

        // Write a few headers
        addCaption(sheet, 0, 0, "Number");
        addCaption(sheet, 1, 0, "Points");
        addCaption(sheet, 2, 0, "Name");
        addCaption(sheet, 3, 0, "Screen Name");


    }

    private int createContent(WritableSheet sheet, List<members> memberList) throws WriteException,
            RowsExceededException {

        int size = memberList.size() ;


        // This is where we will add Data from the JCR
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            members mem =  (members)memberList.get(i) ;

            String number = mem.getNum();
            String points = mem.getScore();
            String name = mem.getName();
            String display = mem.getDisplay();



            // First column
            addLabel(sheet, 0, i+2, number);
            // Second column
            addLabel(sheet, 1, i+2, points);

            // Second column
            addLabel(sheet, 2, i+2,name);

            // Second column
            addLabel(sheet, 3, i+2, display);




        }

        return size;
    }

    private void addCaption(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
            throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
        Label label;
        label = new Label(column, row, s, timesBoldUnderline);
        sheet.addCell(label);
    }

    private void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row,
                           Integer integer) throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
        Number number;
        number = new Number(column, row, integer, times);
        sheet.addCell(number);
    }

    private void addLabel(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
            throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
        Label label;
        label = new Label(column, row, s, times);
        sheet.addCell(label);
    }


    public int exportExcel( List<members> memberList)
    {
        try
        {
            setOutputFile("JCRMembers.xls");
            int recs =  write( memberList);
            return recs ;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the steps described here: [Adobe Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2419182)

1. Select your required page to see component report at http://localhost:4502/etc/reports/compreport.html
2. Now hit the below URL. It gives you JSON output. http://localhost:4502/etc/reports/compreport/jcr:content/report.data.json
3. Copy paste the generated JSON output at below URL and click on JSON to excel http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own logic
create a servlet,
construct Table with data
in the response object add below lines

```
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + reportName + ".csv\"");
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("fileDownload", "true");
cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

once click on the button you will get the report in the Excel format.